# Overriding a method ToString() c# console application

Tags: c#, overriding

Im working on a program that has a generic list of different books. The problem I have is, that my book class should override the method `ToString()` in the superclass `System.Object` so that it shows a string like this:

```
authorFirstName, authorLastName, "bookTitle", year.
```

here is my code for the book class:

```
 class Book
 {
    public string bookTitle
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string authorFirstName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string authorLastName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int publicationYear
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


}
```

And here is my code in `Main`:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
        books.Add(new Book { authorFirstName = "Dumas", authorLastName = "Alexandre", bookTitle = "The Count Of Monte Cristo", publicationYear = 1844 });
        books.Add(new Book { authorFirstName = "Clark", authorLastName = "Arthur C", bookTitle = "Rendezvous with Rama", publicationYear = 1972 });
        books.Add(new Book { authorFirstName = "Dumas", authorLastName = "Alexandre", bookTitle = "The Three Musketeers", publicationYear = 1844 });
        books.Add(new Book { authorFirstName = "Defoe", authorLastName = "Daniel", bookTitle = "Robinson Cruise", publicationYear = 1719 });
        books.Add(new Book { authorFirstName = "Clark", authorLastName = "Arthur C", bookTitle = "2001: A space Odyssey", publicationYear = 1968 });
    }
```

So any idea on what i should do about the "override the method `ToString()` in the superclass `System.Object` so that it returns a string with the following format:"

```
authorFirstName, authorLastName, "bookTitle", year.
```

Comment: code is compiling but failing with StackOverflow. your properties are set incorrect. Change them to smth like:`private string _bookTitle;
        public string bookTitle
        {
            get { return _bookTitle; }
            set { _bookTitle = value; }
        }`

Answer (score 4):

See below:

```
class Book
 {
    public string bookTitle
    {
        get {return bookTitle; }
        set {bookTitle = value; }
    }

    ...

    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", 
                         authorFirstName, authorLastName, bookTitle, 
                         publicationYear);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not override system.Object.ToString()

But you could implement your own collection which does

or you make an [Extensionmethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) to  the List "ListToMyStringFormat" which can be called on the list

Comment: hmm.. okay, so what does it mean by "overriding the method ToString() in the superclass System.Object" ??

Comment: @user2057693 It means that every object in .NET inherits from `System.Object`, which has a method `ToString()`. If you want to override that method in your class (in this case, `Book`), you just need to use the syntax I used in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how to do it:

```
public class User
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<Article> Article { get; set; }

    public String Surname { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return Id.ToString() + Name + Surname;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override to string in the `Book` class, not in `System.Object`. Add the following function to the `Book` class.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.authorFirstName + ", " + this.authorLastName + ", " + this.bookTitle + "," + this.publicationYear.ToString();
}
```